# Combine output from 2 pandas groupbys? Is it possible to combine the two lines of code below so that I have the std dev and skew in the same table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I want to know if it is possible to combine the following cells so that I can have the standard deviation and skew in one table, instead of two separate ones like below.
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please post your code to generate the dataframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
salary.groupby('Rank').agg({'YrsSincePhd':['std','skew']})
```

Comment: is it possible to do this with a column for kurtosis as well?